# UICollectionViewCell's height using custom layout

Tags: ios, swift, layout, collections, view

I have ran into a problem during `UICollectionView` custom layout implementation.

The thing is that I need to calculate collection view cell's height in custom layout's `prepare()`. To do so I have:

```
func heightForItem(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

method in custom layout's delegate protocol which is implemented in my view controller.

However this method is called before cell is dequeued and actually has any data based on which I could calculate it's height. Thus if cell's content exceeds it's initial bounds - I can't see part of content.

Has anyone encountered the same problem with custom layout? How did you solve it?

Protocol for custom layout:

```
protocol CustomLayoutDelegateProtocol: class {
    func numberOfSectionsInRow() -> Int
    func indecesOfSectionsInRow() -> [Int]
    func minimumInteritemSpace() -> CGFloat
    func heightForItem(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
}
```

Custom layout itself:

```
class CustomLayoutClass: UICollectionViewLayout {

    weak var delegate: CustomLayoutDelegateProtocol? {
        didSet {
            setupLayout()
        }
    }

    private var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    private var contentWidth: CGFloat {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return 0 }
        return collectionView.bounds.width
    }
    private var interitemSpace: CGFloat?
    private var numberOfColumns: Int?
    private var columnedSections: [Int]?


    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    private func setupLayout() {
        numberOfColumns = delegate?.numberOfSectionsInRow()
        columnedSections = delegate?.indecesOfSectionsInRow()
        interitemSpace = delegate?.minimumInteritemSpace()
    }

    override func invalidateLayout() {
        cache.removeAll()
        super.invalidateLayout()
    }

    override func prepare() {
        if cache.isEmpty {
            guard let collectionView = collectionView,
                  let numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns,
                  let columnedSections = columnedSections,
                  let interitemSpace = interitemSpace else { return }

            let columnWidth = (contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns))
            var xOffset = [CGFloat]()
            for column in 0..<numberOfColumns {
                var interitemSpace = interitemSpace
                if column == 0 { interitemSpace = 0 }
                xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth + interitemSpace)
            }

            var yOffset: CGFloat = 0.0

            for section in 0..<collectionView.numberOfSections {
                for item in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                    guard let sectionInsets = delegate?.collectionView(collectionView, layout: self, insetForSectionAt: indexPath.section),
                          let height = delegate?.heightForItem(collectionView, at: indexPath) else { continue }
                    let width = columnedSections.contains(section) ? columnWidth : contentWidth

                    let xOffsetIdx = columnedSections.contains(section) ? columnedSections.index(of: section)! % numberOfColumns : 0

                    yOffset += sectionInsets.top
                    let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[xOffsetIdx], y: yOffset, width: width, height: height)

                    let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
                    attributes.frame = frame
                    cache.append(attributes)

                    contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)

                    let isLastInRow = (columnedSections.contains(section) && columnedSections.index(of: section)! % numberOfColumns == (numberOfColumns-1))
                    let isNotColumnedSection = !columnedSections.contains(section)

                    if isLastInRow || isNotColumnedSection {
                        yOffset += height + sectionInsets.bottom
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for attributes in cache {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        return layoutAttributes
    }
}
```

And implementation for protocol (from view controller):

```
extension ViewController: CustomLayoutDelegateProtocol {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    guard let sectionType = InvoiceSectionIndexType(rawValue: section) else { return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0) }

    switch sectionType {
    case .receiver:
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: Constants.bigLineSpace, left: 0, bottom: Constants.bigLineSpace, right: 0)

    default:
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: Constants.commonLineSpace, right: 0)
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInRow() -> Int {
    return Constants.numberOfSectionsInRow
}

func indecesOfSectionsInRow() -> [Int] {
    return [0, 1]
}

func minimumInteritemSpace() -> CGFloat {
    return Constants.interitemSpace
}

func heightForItem(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    guard let sectionType = InvoiceSectionIndexType(rawValue: indexPath.section) else { return 0 }

    switch sectionType {
    case .next:
        return Constants.nextButtonHeight

    default:
        return Constants.estimatedRowHeight
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please show some code so we could help you better

Comment: @user1000 added protocol, layout and protocol implementation in question

Comment: Have you tried UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol for calculating item size?

Comment: @KrishnaKumar FlowLayout doesn’t satisfy my needs in layout so I had to use custom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue on my own and the solution is quite simple though not very obvious.

Since we have indexPath for concrete cell we can find our content (in my case content is simple text which is put into a label). Then we can create label (which we will not display since it's needed only for calculations) with width (in my case I know width for cells) and height which is `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude`. We then apply `sizeToFit()` to our label and now we have label with appropriate height. The only thing we should do now - apply this new height to our cell.

Sample code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath, withWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        // ask your DataSource for piece of data with indexPath

        let testLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        testLabel.text = // your text
        testLabel.sizeToFit()

        if testLabel.bounds.height > Constants.defaultContentLabelHeight {
            return Constants.estimatedRowHeight + (testLabel.bounds.height - Constants.defaultContentLabelHeight)
        } else {
            return Constants.estimatedRowHeight
        }
    }
```